# create a custom StrokeCap in jetpack compose drawScope

Tags: android, canvas, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Is there a way to create a custom stroke for `Stroke: DrawStyle` class in jetpack compose. Currently, there's only three option and i haven't been able to find a way to make it custom. I want to make a custom one that rounds the `edges` of an arc that is being used like this

```
@Composable
fun Chart() {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(1f)
    ) {
        drawIntoCanvas {
            val width = size.width
            val radius = width / 2f
            val strokeWidth = radius * .3f
            var startAngle = 0f

            val items = listOf(25f, 25f, 25f, 25f, 25f, 25f, 25f, 25f)

            items.forEach {
                val sweepAngle = it.toAngle

                drawArc(
                    color = Color.Gray,
                    startAngle = startAngle,
                    sweepAngle = sweepAngle - 5,
                    useCenter = false,
                    topLeft = Offset(strokeWidth / 2, strokeWidth / 2),
                    size = Size(width - strokeWidth, width - strokeWidth),
                    style = Stroke(strokeWidth, cap = StrokeCap.CUSTOM_CORNER_CAP)
                )

                startAngle += sweepAngle
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make it so the arc looks like this
[image]

with the current code it looks like this
[image]

Comment: did you solve the problem? i am currently searching for a solution for this problem..